# grid of figures, caption to the left of each row

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I think the title says it all: I took photos of 5 object from 3 different angles. So for each object there are 3 pics. I would like to display them so there's a row per each object, and in that row the 3 images of that object are displayed.
I know I can do this using subfigure\subcaption, but I want a few extra things I don't know how to achieve:

1. I want to remove the labels from below the figures
2. I want to have the object's name to the left of each row, centered vertically.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a possible solution using the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) and [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{capbesidesep=columnsep,%
capbesideframe=yes,capbesideposition={left,center}}
\begin{figure}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1a}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2a}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3a}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{First row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1b}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2b}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3b}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Second row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1c}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2c}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3c}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Third row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1d}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2d}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3d}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Fourth row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1e}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2e}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3e}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Fifth row of figures}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

If the labels (Figure #:) are not desired, one can simply use `\caption*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{capbesidesep=columnsep,%
capbesideframe=yes,capbesideposition={left,center}}
\begin{figure}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1a}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2a}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3a}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{First row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1b}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2b}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3b}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Second row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1c}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2c}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3c}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Third row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1d}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2d}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3d}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Fourth row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1e}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2e}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3e}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Fifth row of figures}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In a comment, **noam** reports some problem with the solution above and the `wrapfig` package; the following example shows that there's no incompatibility between the packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{}
\DeclareCaptionSubType{figure}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{format=myformat}

\begin{document}

\thisfloatsetup{capbesidesep=columnsep,%
capbesideframe=yes,capbesideposition={left,center}}
\begin{figure}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1a}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2a}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3a}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{First row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1b}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2b}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3b}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Second row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1c}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2c}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3c}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Third row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1d}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2d}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3d}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Fourth row of figures}}
\fcapside[\FBwidth]
{\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image1e}}%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image2e}}\quad
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}}{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{image3e}}%
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption*{Fifth row of figures}}
\end{figure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{6cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{image}
\caption{text}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, but it seems that the floatrow package doesn't work well with the wrapfig package which I am also using

Comment: @noam as far as I know, they work well together; if something is not working for you, please provide a minimal document illustrating the problem and add it as an edit to your question.

Comment: @noam I updated my answer with an example using my code and the `wrapfig` package; as you can see, there's no incompatibility and the result is as expected, so if you are having problems, please compose a minimal working document (as the one in my answer) allowing us to reproduce the problem

Comment: Thanks you very much! You shouldn't have gone to all that trouble. Of course, when you said you know them to work together well I started disassembling my code to understand the problem.

Comment: @noam No problem at all ;-) Are you still having problems with your code or is everything working now?

Comment: still not working... I have other issues I need to attend to (paper deadline coming up :) so I'll get back to this later